# Some corrected issues persist on SonarQube?

Tags: c#, resharper, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1.2

We're using `sonar-runner-2.4` and `sonarqube-5.1.2` on a C# .Net 4.5.2 solution.

Very usefull products, by the way :)

We had a bit of trouble with this;

> https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6792

Because `Sonar` tried to decorate issues beyond the file limit. It seems to be a fix. We've got simple workarounds (once we know on which file the decorators fail) for that and waiting for the fix.

Now, there's this problem which we think is related to **SONAR-6792** (to be confirmed).

We have several cases where code issues are detected although they are already corected. It's like the analysis is being done on some old code view or issues are decorated on wrong lines. Here's one of the examples :

[Sonar corrected issue](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-7GEFi8Bbt6Y/Ve2G59x2SSI/AAAAAAAAN8s/nEgyyXcb1zc/s1280-Ic42/wrong-sonar-issue.png)

Resharper tells us that;

> Parameter can be of type 'IEnumerable' " but it's
>   already the case. The previous type was probably an
>   'ICollection' .

Thanks!

Comment: Here are some other examples : https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-9Jg--dYAlk8/VgD9X77czFI/AAAAAAAAN90/h0zz1AA-Qlk/s998-Ic42/wrong-sonar-issue-2.png https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-fjHdDalfdP4/VgD9YFWscuI/AAAAAAAAN94/UqQmgMIPrtQ/s950-Ic42/wrong-sonar-issue-3.png Issues are clearly decorated on the wrong lines . Still no one from Sonar can state anything?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem seems to be external to Sonar itself. Our Sonar build is a bit customized. It doesn't use the R# plugin for Sonar, but it uses R# itself and feeds the output to Sonar.

Installing a newer version of R# solved the problem, for now.

We're sorry for the any caused inconvenience.

Thanks!